# How to read a JSON payload from a DELETE request on Sanic Framework?

Tags: sanic

On the frontend, I'm sending a DELETE request with a JSON Payload. This works fine and the data is correctly send, but in the backend - using Sanic Framework - the request's body is empty.

```
print(request.body) # b''
print(request.json) # None
```

How can I access the request's body from a DELETE request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Sanic will not consume the body of a DELETE. There are two alternatives:

**Option #1 - Tell Sanic to consume the body**

```py
@app.delete("/path", ignore_body=False)
async def handler(_):
    ...
```

**Option #2 - Manually consume the body in the handler**

```py
@app.delete("/path")
async def handler(request: Request):
    await request.receive_body()
```

[Release notes](https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/release-notes/v21.3.html#what-to-know)
[API docs](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sanic/api/app.html#sanic.app.Sanic.route)

Comment: I have made a note to add this to the User guide documentation so it is more visible

Comment: The docs are more explicit now https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/basics/routing.html#http methods

Comment: how to do the same in class-based views with decorator has some attribute?